# Algorithm used to implement the Python str.count function

Tags: python, algorithm

I came across the Python `str.count` function while reading the documentation. I can't seem to find any good explanation on the inner working of the function. What algorithm is used to count the number of substrings in a string? How does it actually work?

Comment: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/String_searching_algorithm links to some algorithms for substring search in string, with different time and space complexities. Not sure which one Python uses.

Comment: Have you read the source code? That's what I do when I ask myself these kinds of questions.

Answer (score 7):

Study the source code at https://github.com/python/cpython/blob/master/Objects/stringlib/fastsearch.h

A comment at the top of file explains this much:

> fast search/count implementation, based on a mix between boyer- moore
>   and horspool, with a few more bells and whistles on the top. for some
>   more background, see: http://effbot.org/zone/stringlib.htm

Answer (score -2):

I've tried to do a simple code to count how many "r" in a List of words using Python:

```
fruit = ["apple", "banana", "rrrrrrrrr", "cherry", "berrada"]
y=0
for j in range(len(fruit)):
  x = fruit[j].count("r")
  y = y + x
  
print(y)
```

It might help you understand how the count function works.