# What's the computational cost of count operation on strings Python?

Tags: python, python-2.7, big-o

For example:

```
'hello'.count('e')
```

Is this O(n)? I'm guessing the way it works is it scans `'hello'` and increments a counter each time the letter `'e'` is seen. How can I know this without guessing? I tried reading the source code [here](https://hg.python.org/cpython/file/2.7/Lib/string.py), but got stuck upon finding this:

```
def count(s, *args):
    """count(s, sub[, start[,end]]) -> int

    Return the number of occurrences of substring sub in string
    s[start:end].  Optional arguments start and end are
    interpreted as in slice notation.

    """
    return s.count(*args)
```

Where can I read about what's executed in `s.count(*args)`?

edit: I understand what `*args` does in the context of Python functions.

Comment: @cricket_007: Why would you think *that's* an appropriate dupe target? The `*` doesn't seem to have anything to do with the questioner's confusion.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16806972/algorithm-used-to-implement-the-python-str-count-function

Answer (score 13, accepted):

`str.count` is implemented in native code, in the [`stringobject.c`](https://hg.python.org/cpython/file/2.7/Objects/stringobject.c#l2119) file, which delegates to either [`stringlib_count`](https://hg.python.org/cpython/file/2.7/Objects/stringlib/count.h), or [`PyUnicode_Count`](https://hg.python.org/cpython/file/2.7/Objects/unicodeobject.c#l5374) which itself delegates to `stringlib_count` again. `stringlib_count` ultimately uses [`fastsearch`](https://hg.python.org/cpython/file/2.7/Objects/stringlib/fastsearch.h) to search for occurrences of the substring in the string and counting those.

For one-character strings (e.g. your `'e'`), it is short-circuited to the following code path:

```
for (i = 0; i < n; i++)
    if (s[i] == p[0]) {
        count++;
        if (count == maxcount)
            return maxcount;
    }
return count;
```

So yes, this is exactly as you assumed a simple iteration over the string sequence and counting the occurences of the substring.

For search strings longer than a single character it gets a bit more complicated, due to handling overlaps etc., and the logic is buried deeper in the `fastsearch` implementation. But it’s essentially the same: a linear search through the string.

So yes, `str.count` is in linear time, O(n). And if you think about it, it makes a lot of sense: In order to know how often a substring appears in a string, you need to look at every possible substring of the same length. So for a substring length of 1, you have to look at every character in the string, giving you a linear complexity.

Btw. for more information about the underlying fastsearch algorithm, see [this article on effbot.org](http://effbot.org/zone/stringlib.htm).

---

For Python 3, which only has a single Unicode string type, the links to the implementations are: [`unicode_count`](https://hg.python.org/cpython/file/3.5/Objects/unicodeobject.c#l9121) which uses [`stringlib_count`](https://hg.python.org/cpython/file/3.5/Objects/stringlib/count.h) which uses [`fastsearch`](https://hg.python.org/cpython/file/3.5/Objects/stringlib/fastsearch.h).

Comment: The complexity for a `k`-character string is `O((n-k)k)`. The worst case scenario is a searching a string like `000000` for a string like `001`. The loop goes through the first `n-k` characters and compares the first element (for `n-k` comparisons). It then goes through the next `k-1` elements (for `(n-k)(k-1)` comparisons). This reaches a maximum at `k=n/2` with complexity `O(0.25n^2)`.

Comment: @JaredGoguen: For a naive string search, that would be the correct analysis. Python's search is a lot more sophisticated than that, though. I *think* it still has the same worst-case asymptotic runtime bound as the naive algorithm, but there are ways to get the worst case down to O(n). I think Python sacrifices worst-case performance for better usual-case performance.

Comment: @user2357112 This analysis was based off of the code in the `fastsearch` source. The nested loop can clearly be seen in `for (i = 0; i <= w; i++) { ... for (j = 0; j < mlast; j++) { ... }}`. Here, `m` is the length of the matching string and `w` is `n-m`. I'm not a C person, so I might be mistaken.

Comment: @JaredGoguen: You've overlooked the skip logic. The search usually jumps `i` forward a distance much greater than 1, and there's an extra condition you have to meet to enter the candidate match checking. Something like `'0'*1000+'1' in '0'*100000` takes under a millisecond, but you can still defeat the optimizations with something like `'0'*1000+'100' in '0'*100000`, which forces a candidate match check each time and a `skip` value of 0.

Answer (score 1):

Much of python's library code is written in C.  The code you are looking for is here:

http://svn.python.org/view/python/trunk/Objects/stringobject.c?view=markup

```
static PyMethodDef
string_methods[] = {
    // ...
    {"count", (PyCFunction)string_count, METH_VARARGS, count__doc__},
    // ...
    {NULL,     NULL}                         /* sentinel */
};

static PyObject *
string_count(PyStringObject *self, PyObject *args) {
    ...
}
```

Answer (score 1):

If you pursue @AJNeufeld's answer a little ways, you will eventually come upon this link, which explains how the (then-)new find logic works. It's a combination of several string searching approaches, with the intent of benefiting from some of the logic, but avoiding the up-front table setup costs for searches: http://effbot.org/zone/stringlib.htm

Boyer-Moore is a famous string searching algorithm. BM-Horspool and BM-Sunday are variants that improve on the original in certain ways. Google will find you more than you ever wanted to know about these.