# Can someone help me understand the time complexity differential between these two solutions?

Tags: python, big-o

I recently solved a problem on leetcode, where it asked you to find the first unique character in a string. The constraints were:

1. s consists of only lowercase English letters
2. 1 <= s.length <= 105

My solution was pretty good, scoring in the 80th percentile, but I pulled up a 98th percentile solution to compare, and I don't understand why my solution is slower. Can someone explain the difference in time efficiency between the two solutions?

#98th percentile solution

```
class Solution(object):
    def firstUniqChar(self, s):
        #O(1)?
        ind = float('inf')
        
        #O(n)?
        m = set(s)
        
        #max 26 loops, due to constraints: all characters are lowercase letters
        for i in m:
            
            #O(n)?
            if s.count(i) == 1:
                
                #O(n)?
                if s.index(i) < ind:
                    #O(1)
                    ind = s.index(i)
        
        return -1 if ind == float('inf') else ind
```

#My solution

```
class Solution(object):
    def firstUniqChar(self, s):
        
        s_dict = {}
        #O(n)
        for x in s:
            #O(1)
            if x in s_dict:
                s_dict[x] += 1
            #O(1)
            else:
                s_dict[x] = 1
        
        #O(n), breaks after first unique is found
        for i,x in enumerate(s):
            #O(1)
            if s_dict[x] == 1:
                return i
            
        return -1
```

Comment: Your solution potentially loops over the entire string twice, there's loops over a subset of it once.  Yours requires dictionary access, which is relatively fast but not as fast as indexing something like a list.  I couldn't give a detailed breakdown of all the effects, but that's what jumped out at me.

Comment: @defladamouse You're probably correct that my solution loops more over the string. But I thought that ```m = set(s)``` and ```s.count(i)```, would have to loop over the string multiple times more than mine. Maybe those are both O(1)?

Comment: I can't be sure, I don't know how functions like count work under the hood.  I suggest experimenting with the `%timeit` function in ipython.  As an experiment I compared `count` to a short function to reproduce the behaviour, count was a factor 10 faster.

Comment: `str.count` is implemented in C whereas your counting method is implemented in python. You can find a more detailed answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/35855968/12479639)

Comment: @defladamouse
Thank you! ```%timeit``` seems like a useful tool, curious to see how count works. Appreciate your time.

Comment: dont take leetcode running time seriiously , if you run same code your run time will change and it wont be same again. just look for time complexity

Comment: @Axe319 Awwww that makes sense Axe, thank you for pointing that out!

Comment: Another thing to take into consideration, `s_dict[x] += 1` is creating `n` integer objects under the hood since an `int` is immutable. So for a string of length `1,000,000` it needs to create a `1,000,000` `int` objects.

Comment: @Axe319 Thank you again, Axe. Excellent information, both comments are concepts that I wasn't thinking about. I'd like the comments if I had enough rep to do so.

Comment: @Axe319 I switched my ```s_dict[x]+=1``` line to a boolean check and the solution did bump me up to the 90th+ percentile. Still not quite as fast as the c based functions, but I'm happy that I understand what's going on. Thank you again.