# Why count() method is faster than a for loop python

Tags: python

Here are 2 functions that do exactly the same thing, but does anyone know why the one using the `count()` method is much faster than the other? (I mean how does it work? How is it built?)

If possible, I'd like a more understandable answer than what's found here : [Algorithm used to implement the Python str.count function](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16806972/algorithm-used-to-implement-the-python-str-count-function) 
or what's in the source code : https://hg.python.org/cpython/file/tip/Objects/stringlib/fastsearch.h

```
def scoring1(seq):
    score = 0
    for i in range(len(seq)):
       if seq[i] == '0':
           score += 1      
    return score

def scoring2(seq):
    score = 0
    score = seq.count('0') 
    return score

seq = 'AATTGGCCGGGGAG0CTTC0CTCC000TTTCCCCGGAAA'
# takes 1min15 when applied to 100 sequences larger than 100 000 characters
score1  = scoring1(seq)
# takes 10 sec when applied to 100 sequences larger than 100 000 characters
score2  = scoring2(seq)
```

Thanks a lot for your reply

Comment: The short answer is because a bunch of really smart people have been optimizing built in functions like `count()` since python was released

Comment: What computer did you try this on? Mine is apparently 100-200 times faster than yours. Also, why the unpythonic indexed looping? Were you **trying** to make it slow?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Algorithm used to implement the Python str.count function](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16806972/algorithm-used-to-implement-the-python-str-count-function)

Comment: @StefanPochmann, I assume you tried it with the sequence given, but the data I use are much bigger, that's why I have those different runtimes. And what is the unpythonic indexed looping you're talking about ?

Comment: @Tana No, of course I didn't do it with the sequence given, otherwise I'd be a few more orders of magnitude faster. I tried it with `seq * 2565`, since that's larger than 100000 characters. The unpythonic indexed looping is in your `scoring1`. See @JohnColeman's `scoring2` for normal looping.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

@CodeMonkey has already given the answer, but it is potentially interesting to note that your first function can be improved so that it runs about 20% faster:

```
import time, random

def scoring1(seq):
    score=0
    for i in range(len(seq)):
       if seq[i]=='0':
           score+=1      
    return score

def scoring2(seq):
    score=0
    for x in seq:
       score += (x =='0')    
    return score

def scoring3(seq):
    score = 0
    score = seq.count('0') 
    return score

def test(n):
    seq = ''.join(random.choice(['0','1']) for i in range(n))
    functions = [scoring1,scoring2,scoring3]
    for i,f in enumerate(functions):
        start = time.clock()
        s = f(seq)
        elapsed = time.clock() - start
        print('scoring' + str(i+1) + ': ' + str(s) + ' computed in ' + str(elapsed) + ' seconds')

test(10**7)
```

Typical output:

```
scoring1: 5000742 computed in 0.9651326495293333 seconds
scoring2: 5000742 computed in 0.7998054195159483 seconds
scoring3: 5000742 computed in 0.03732172598339578 seconds
```

Both of the first two approaches are blown away by the built-in `count()`.

Moral of the story: when you are *not* using an already optimized built-in method, you need to optimize your own code.

Comment: Use `timeit` next time

Comment: @Chris_Rands That is a good idea -- but I sometimes use `time` if I am satisfied with a ball-park figure.

Answer (score 3):

Because count is executed in the underlying native implementation. The for-loop is executed in slower interpreted code.